# Which font embedding technique allows one to suppress anti-aliasing?

Tags: html, css, text, fonts

I'm bewildered by all the different font embedding techniques, Cufon, @font-face, FLIR, Typekit, etc., and don't know where to begin with this, especially since there's just one specific behaviour I need. Are there any font embedding techniques that will render a font without anti-aliasing/smoothing/ClearTyping?

I have always just designed to whatever my computer/monitor renders and haven't even thought about it twice. But with this particular site, I'm using opacity on a div that floats on a glassy PNG and the ClearType is just a disaster. The ClearType anti-aliasing on this background combo is standing out darkly, creating what's essentially a bolded font. If I apply an alpha opacity filter on IE8, it removes the ClearTyping, showing me just the single pixel strokes and it looks perfect.

So, do any of the font-embedding techniques allow one to disable anti-aliasing rendering on the font cross-browser? I know probably sIFR would, but would really prefer not to use Flash, as my target audience would most likely be the chief one out there who wouldn't keep it updated: B&M companies.

Comment: I went down this road a while back and it ended with "the browser decides", hopefully things have progressed since then!

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, no font-embedding technique will allow you to suppress anti-aliasing. What you need is a CSS property to tell the browser that you'd prefer if some elements on your page were not anti-aliased.

Now, whilst this may not be helpful to all your endeavours, especially if a large portion of your audience isn't using WebKit-based browsers, some WebKit browsers support something similar to the [proposed `font-smooth` CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-font/#font-smooth), as explained in [Max Voltar's post on font-smoothing](http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing), using:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: none;
```

Would be similar to the W3C proposed `font-smooth` property:

```
font-smooth: never;
```

Max's article also links to [a demo page by Christoph Zillgens](http://files.christophzillgens.com/webkit-font-smoothing.html) which shows you the effect in action, with a caveat that it only appears to work on OS X.

As Aram Kocharyan says above, it may well be that – right now – you can't rely on this property and would have to leave it to let the browser decide.

Some earlier Internet Explorer engines also alias the text if the `opacity` is set to anything other than 1 – you could try 0.999 as the value and see what happens there.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Yes, I have played around with that. Unfortunately, no go; it doesn't seem to be working in my Chrome. Also, I can tell you have a handle on my demographic, and they most likely won't be using anything WebKit.

Comment: Did you try the opacity hack? It may not be 0.999, but a (slightly) lower value. Your other option would be to try `-ms-font-smoothing` and set that to never – likely only to work in IE10 (perhaps IE9) though I have no idea.

Comment: Yes, I did try the opacity hack. It's how I discovered that IE8 clears smoothing. So at least on those who haven't updated their browsers, I'll have aliasing on this font. It's not very futureproof though. I hope `font-smooth` becomes a reality.